# How to get to command line

Tags: command-line

Some well-meaning person installed Ubuntu on my wife's formerly Windows laptop.  She hadn't used it for years before I married her.  I haven't used Ubuntu since fifteen or twenty years ago myself, so of course the GUI is completely different.  (Actually, I had Kubuntu back then.)

It has auto-login to her admin account but she doesn't know the password.  The search function in the GUI cannot locate any *.jpg in /home although I know there are hundreds of them in one folder on the desktop.

So, I want to open a shell window to use `find`

There are a lot of icons in the launcher/task bar/dock/whatever it's called but none of them are a terminal emulator.

The "software center" shows several terminal emulators installed, but I can't launch any of them, and the "more info" buttons do nothing.

I want to find all of her pictures to put them on a newer machine and retire this one.  I can pull the disk and hook it up directly to another laptop (where I have root access) but it would be more pleasant to just type commands.  :-)

Comment: You didn't tell us what release of Ubuntu, but most desktop files are in ~/Desktop (ie. `/home/$USER/Desktop` where $USER is your username).  Have you tried CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal using the shortcut.

Comment: My question was correctly tagged a duplicate, and the answers over there worked.  I can’t remember how to check the version in the GUI on the release I used last, which is probably different anyway.